# Wordpress Plugin installation error: parent director not writable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to install a plugin for my Wordpress by uploading a zip file. However it is giving me an error and asking if the parent directory is writable. I've tried going to the upload setting however all I am shown is a check box to organize folders into dates and nothing to do with the upload path. I have tried changing the permissions and as well doing define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );. The solution i keep getting linked to doesn't help at all. nothing seems to work. What does it even mean that the parent directory isn't writable, does it not exist or not have permissions?

The image shows what i currently see in my settings/media section